# Using VBA to control IE to login to a website

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I'm new to this, but I'm practising, and it seemed to me that logging into my Institute's website ought to be the easiest thing in the world. Right? Well, it's driving me crazy.

Specifically, the program fails at 
  `page.Document.getElementById("edit-name").Value = 1234`

Run time error 424 "object required"

Also, and I'm not sure if this is related, when I type "page." the VBA editor helpfully provides a list of options, and I select Document. When I type the second "." to get "page.Document." I do not then get a further list of options.

Here's the complete program, and thanks for any help

```
Public Sub MyLogin()

'This uses early binding
'In menu at top of page - Tools...Reference.... Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library must both be ticked



 Dim page As InternetExplorer
 Set page = New InternetExplorer
 page.Visible = True

 Dim MyLink As Object

'Login at Institute website
 page.Navigate "http://www.actuaries.org.uk/"


 Do While page.Busy Or page.ReadyState <> 4
   DoEvents
 Loop



 For Each MyLink In page.Document.Links
   If InStr(MyLink.href, "/user") Then MyLink.Click: Exit For
 Next MyLink

 Do While page.Busy Or page.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
 Loop

 'Are now at the login page
 'Enter username, password and click


  page.Document.getElementById("edit-name").Value = 1234
  page.Document.getElementById("edit-pass").Value = "01/01/1977"
  page.Document.getElementById("edit-submit").Click




  End Sub
```

Comment: Difficult to make suggestions without the relevant source HTML.  If I had to guess I'd say there's no element with id "edit-name".

Comment: Share the source HTML of the web page. Either the `edit-name` element does not exist or is not a `input` tag. The issue may also be that the page has not fully loaded. Try debugging the code (put a breakpoint at the erroneous line) and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

> Specifically, the program fails at  page.Document.getElementById("edit-name").Value = 1234

Nothing wrong with that line.

One reason that I can think of is that your `For` Loop is not executed. To avoid that, directly navigate to the relevant `url`. This trimmed version works for me.

[image]

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sUrl As String: sUrl = "https://www.actuaries.org.uk/user"
    Dim ie As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True

    ie.navigate sUrl

    Do While ie.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    ie.Document.getElementById("edit-name").Value = 1234
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that. Indeed, navigating directly to the login page does work. (I altered my code to cut out the step of clicking on the link.)  However, I really cannot understand why the clicking on link idea is not working. It's definitely bringing up the correct page - I can see that as the browser is visible. I can also 'inspect' the 'edit-name' element on the page. It's all there, fully opened.

Comment: I just tried your original code and it works just fine :)

Comment: In that case, I would recommend sticking with the trimmed version of my code. :)

Comment: I take it that the Excel version should not make any difference? I'm using 2003. I tried the code on a different machine, also using 2003, with the same results.

Comment: No but IE versions have known to create problems